# Write list of dictionary values to file

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries such as:

```
values = [{'Name': 'John Doe', 'Age': 26, 'ID': '1279abc'},
          {'Name': 'Jane Smith', 'Age': 35, 'ID': 'bca9721'}
         ]
```

What I'd like to do is print this list of dictionaries to a tab delimited text file to look something like this:

```
 Name    Age    ID
John Doe    26    1279abc
Jane Smith     35    bca9721
```

However, I am unable to wrap my head around simply printing the values, as of right now I'm printing the entire dictionary per row via:

```
for i in values: 
    f.write(str(i))
    f.write("\n")
```

Perhaps I need to iterate through each dictionary now? I've seen people use something like:

```
for i, n in iterable:
    pass
```

But I've never understood this. Anyone able to shed some light into this?

EDIT:

Appears that I could use something like this, unless someone has a more pythonic way (Perhaps someone can explain "for i, n in interable"?):

```
for dic in values:
    for entry in dic:
        f.write(dic[entry])
```

Comment: Can you guarantee that each dictionary has the same keys?

Comment: Yes, the keys are retrieved through keys = values[0].keys().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simple enough to accomplish with a [`DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter).  Its purpose is to write column-separated data, but if we specify our delimiter to be that of tabs instead of commas, we can make this work just fine.

```
from csv import DictWriter
values = [{'Name': 'John Doe', 'Age': 26, 'ID': '1279abc'},
          {'Name': 'Jane Smith', 'Age': 35, 'ID': 'bca9721'}]
keys = values[0].keys()
with open("new-file.tsv", "w") as f:
    dict_writer = DictWriter(f, keys, delimiter="\t")
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    for value in values:
        dict_writer.writerow(value)
```

Comment: This worked great, however when opening the file in Excel (notepad looks great) every second row is a blank, can you explain this?

Comment: Since I'm on Linux I can't vouch for what Excel is doing with this data. However, I imagine that you can import it into excel and specify the delimiter as tabs.

Comment: I found the reason, the "lineterminator" parameter helps out. linux uses unix style line ending "\r\n" instead of "\n". Thank you for your solution!

Comment: It's Windows that uses CRLF and Unix that uses LF.

Answer (score 0):

```
f.write('Name\tAge\tID')
for value in values:
    f.write('\t'.join([value.get('Name'), str(value.get('Age')), value.get('ID')]))
```

Comment: why `value.get('Name')` instead of `value['Name']`?

Comment: The only practical difference is that `get()` returns `None` if the key doesn't exist, while indexing a key that doesn't exist produces a traceback.

Comment: `None` is already returned by default in that situation.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, sorry was meant to say returned `''` instead. `value.get('Name', '')`.

Comment: I didn't see any indication in the question that the dictionary would be sparse, so I think that `get()` rather than `[]` is a purely stylistic choice here. I'm simply more used to `get()`.

Comment: True it's only code styling difference in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably thinking of the items() method. This will return the key and value for each entry in the dictionary. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_items.htm

```
for k,v in values.items():
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# assuming your dictionary is in values
import csv
with open('out.txt', 'w') as fout:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(fout, fields=values.keys(). delimiter="\t")
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow(values.values())
```